# How to download multiple links in to a single file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, aria2

How can I download multiple links in to a single file using `aria2c`? This works but it will still download all the links as seperate files.

```
aria2c -i links.txt --o result.txt
```

Comment: Please ask your sysadmin or ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: Provide a minimal verifiable input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following custom command:

```
aria2c2 links.txt results.txt
```

By defining this function:

```
function aria2c2() {                                                             
    mkdir output && \                                                            
    aria2c -i $1 --dir output && \                                               
    cat output/* > $2 && \                                                       
    rm -r output                                                                 
}
```

This will download the contents the links point to and combine them into one text file called "results.txt". This assumes you're working only with text.

To define the function for each new terminal, place it in your `~/.bashrc` file. Load it in the current terminal by entering `source ~/.bashrc`.

---

This doesn't answer your question (i.e. how to do this with aria2c alone), but it's the best I've got and I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: might as well use curl + xargs maybe cat

Comment: function aria2c2() {                                                             
    mkdir output && \                                                            
    aria2c -i $1 --dir output && \                                               
    cat output/* > $2 && \                                                       
    rm -r output                                                                 
}

Comment: And then you could enter: aria2c2 links.txt results.txt